# Sorting a column into category

Tags: r

I have a table with name and height as the two columns. 
I would like to classify people who are above 6 feet, below 4 feet and between 4 and 6 feet are classified as tall,short and average respectively.

I am trying to do this in R-studio.Even a method to classify them in an separate column is also fine.

```
**Name     Height**
 James       5.6
 John        3.7
 Ron         6.8
 Tor         5.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data:

```
Name<-c("James", "John", "Ron", "Tor")
Height<-c(5.6,3.7,6.8,5.2)
dat<-data.frame(Name,Height)
```

You could do this by creating a new variable and adding categories according to your criteria:

```
dat$group<-"average"
dat$group[dat$Height<=4] <-"short" 
dat$group[dat$Height>=6] <-"tall" 


#   Name Height   group
#1 James    5.6 average
#2  John    3.7   short
#3   Ron    6.8    tall
#4   Tor    5.2 average
```

Answer (score 2):

Use, `cut`

```
 dat <- structure(list(Name = c("James", "John", "Ron", "Tor"), Height = c(5.6, 
 3.7, 6.8, 5.2)), .Names = c("Name", "Height"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -4L))

 dat$class <- with(dat,
                cut(Height, 
                      breaks=c(-Inf,4,6,Inf),labels=c("short", "average", "tall")) )
 dat
#   Name Height   class
# 1 James    5.6 average
# 2  John    3.7   short
# 3   Ron    6.8    tall
# 4   Tor    5.2 average

class(dat$class)
#[1] "factor"
```

If you need a "character" variable, you can choose `labels=F` and

```
  dat$class <- with(dat, c("short","average", "tall")[cut(Height,breaks=c(-Inf,4,6,Inf), labels=F)])

class(dat$class)
#[1] "character"
```

Comment: I think how you had it before the edit was easier to follow along

Comment: @Ricardo Saporta, I just formatted the code, I hope it is easier to read now. :-)

Answer (score 2):

`cut` is one way but it does give you a factor. Another way is `findInterval` and ising it as an index gives a character vector:

```
 c('short','average','tall')[ findInterval(dat$Height, c(-Inf, 4,6,Inf) ) ]
```